# JS - text output to the modal window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, output

```
> sorry for my english)
```

> In a nutshell: need to pass the text when the button is clicked into a
> modal window

Hi all. I have a product card, and I need to make it so that when the button is pressed, information from product description is transmitted - to the modal window. Tried to do it through innerHTML/outerHTML, but the description from one card - is passed to all modal windows. The title in the card can be unique, respectively - in each modal window should be a unique title. For each card to create its own window - not rational, therefore, please help))

P.s. Such a mechanism can easily be turned around in jQuery, like this:

```
$('.button_mini').each(function(i)) {
 $(this).on('click', function() {
  $('#order .modal_descr').text($('.catalog-item__subtitle').eq(i).text());
 })}
```

But, I would not like to connect jQuery for the sake of it, so I would like to implement this functionality in native js

Here, by the way, is my unsuccessful attempt to implement it:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button_mini").forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function () {
          document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('is-visible');
          document.querySelector("#order").classList.add('is-visible');
          document.querySelector('.modal__descr').outerHTML = (document.querySelector('.catalog-  item__subtitle').item.outerHTML);

      });

  });
```

> HTML:

Product cards:

```
<div class="catalog-item">
   <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
     <div class="catalog-item__content">
       <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
          <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Watches</div>
          <div class="catalog-item__descr">description</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Buy</button>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
     <div class="catalog-item__content">
        <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
           <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Shoes</div>
           <div class="catalog-item__descr">description</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Buy</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Modal window:

```
<div class="modal" id="order">
        <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
        <div class="modal__subtitle">Your order:</div>
        <div class="modal__descr">Descr/Title from card</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roman and welcome to SO. It looks like your question should contain HTML that goes with the JavaScript snippet. Could you show us the HTML relevant to the question?

Comment: it looks like when you attach the event listener, you are using querySelector that select only one element, and putting its value to all the modals. do you have a specific class or id for each element?

Comment: Added html. 
QuerySelectorAll and GetElementsByClassNames - does not process in such a use, as I showed above in my attempt to. There are no Id and no classes. I would like to implement through a loop, which sets an index for each element of "catalog-item__descr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). This means adding a single event listener that listens for all the lements in the page. In the event handler, check if the clicked element is the `.button_mini` inside of a `.catalog-item`.  If so, then read the text from the `catalog-item__subtitle` element and set it to the `.modal__descr` element.

```
const modal = document.querySelector('#order');
const modalDescription = modal.querySelector('.modal__descr');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const isButtonMini = event.target.matches('.catalog-item .button_mini');

  if (!isButtonMini) {
    return;
  }

  // Select the .catalog-item related to the .button_mini. From there get the subtitle.
  const parent = event.target.closest('.catalog-item');
  const subtitle = parent.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle');

  modalDescription.textContent = subtitle.textContent;

  modal.classList.add('is-visible');
  overlay.classList.add('is-visible');
});
```

Comment: My goodness, You are a magician!))
Thank You)
Everything genius is simple))